# Save check box values to firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my form I have several checkboxes. All selected checkbox values should be written in firebase database. However, cannot manipulate the checkboxes. My code does not take the checkbox values. It does not appear on firebase. My form looks like this [![Form][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FEN4.png

HTML Code

```
 <td>
                            <label>
                                <input class="paint" id = "paint" value="Anti-Fungus Paint" type="checkbox" unchecked> Anti-Fungus Paint
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <input class="paint" id = "paint" value="Emulsion Paint" type="checkbox" unchecked> Emulsion Paint
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <input class="paint" id = "paint" value="Anti-Corrosive Paint" type="checkbox" unchecked> Anti-Corrosive Paint
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <input class="paint" id = "paint" value="All in one Paint" type="checkbox" unchecked> All in one Paint
                            </label>
                        </td>
```

Javasript

```
document.getElementById('formBid').addEventListener('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var id=Date.now();  //generating a unqiue id
            set(ref(db,'quotes/' + id),{
               paint:document.querySelectorAll('input[id="paint"]:checked'),
              
            });
            alert('Quote Sent To Client');
            formBid.reset();
```

Comment: The `formBid` element that your JavaScript listens to is not declared in the HTML you shared. Overall: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so I recommend setting a breakpoint on each line of yuor code, running in a debugger, and check the value of each variable on each line. When you do this: what is the first line where a variable doesn't have the value you expect it to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you should difference the id of each checkbox, the id should be unique to make it works.
I usually use getElementById to get each value because it's easier for me.